# Facebook Graph API /feed returning a bunch of activity posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I make a call to `user_id/feed` in the graph api using my graph token, whether it is the currently authenticated user or any other user, I am getting mostly activity posts such as "user liked this" or "user commented on this". If I use a graph explorer access token I get back a normal feed without the activity results.  I am not sure what is the difference.  I don't want all the activity stories when I make this call.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can do.

**First**

Narrow down what information you want from Facebook. Every /feed object returned from Facebook will have a list of people who commented and liked the post.

```
{user-id}/feed?fields=story,description,name,full_picture,message,type
```

**Second**

If you are missing the permission read_stream you won't be able to get this information. You can debug your tokens here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I was wondering about how to not get just "activity" items when making this call to /user/feed.  It doesn't happen to me in the graph explorer and I have tried lots of different combinations of permissions.

Comment: There isn't a call to exclude a certain type of post. The user/feed argument will return everything that users has done on Facebook but if just want certain types of post you'll be able to filter those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the status_type field in your query. These types of posts have status_type=null